# How to hide Visio 2013 when using interop assembly in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, office-interop, visio, powershell-4.0, visio2013

I'm willing to run Visio 2013 silently through PowerShell.
At the moment I use the following code:

```
Add-Type -Path 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.dll'

$visio = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.ApplicationClass
$visio.Visible = $false
$visio.Quit()
```

The code works but I briefly see the Visio splash screen before it is hidden.
I would like to create the application object using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application` or `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.InvisibleApp` but I can't find the right syntax.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$visio = New-Object -ComObject Visio.InvisibleApp
$visio.Quit()
```

Note that it's not a must to use Add-Type (however you can go also with Add-Type, in this case try Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.InvisibleAppClass

BTW, there is a library for using Visio from PS:
https://visioautomation.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you for helping, why do you say it's not a must tu use `Add-Type`? `New-Object Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.InvisibleAppClass` works fine and it is a call to a .NET interop. I assume using the .NET interop is better than using the COM object, am I wrong?

Comment: It's basically the same thing, just written differently - this way it's shorter :)